# SQL Update not working after using SQL to build columns in a bound DataGridView-VB

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am Using VB Windows Forms with a databound DataGridView control. Using Access, I have a "Customers" table and am using SQL commands to populate selected fields to the DataGridView.  PROBLEM: I have an "Active" field with 1 for active and 0 for inactive.  In the DataGridView window I need to change the "Active" column to display Y for active and N for inactive (without changing the underlying data). I have tried to use the UPDATE command without success. After the first SQL commands to populate the DataGridView, I'm not sure how to code the second SQL command to modify the "Active" column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do anything in the SQL.  The grid can handle it for you, with a bit of code. 
 You need to handle the [`CellFormatting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting) and [`CellParsing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellparsing) events of the grid and first confirm that it is that column.  When formatting, you convert from 1 and 0 to "Y" and "N" respectively and, when parsing, you do the inverse. E.g.

```
Private activeColumnIndex As Integer 'Set column index as appropriate.

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting
    If e.ColumnIndex = activeColumnIndex Then
        Select Case CInt(e.Value)
            Case 0
                e.Value = "N"
            Case 1
                e.Value = "Y"
        End Select

        e.FormattingApplied = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellParsing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellParsingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellParsing
    If e.ColumnIndex = activeColumnIndex Then
        Select Case CStr(e.Value)
            Case "N"
                e.Value = 0
            Case "Y"
                e.Value = 1
        End Select

        e.ParsingApplied = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that this code doesn't account for `NULL` values or invalid input. That's out of scope and up to you to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about this further, I'd suggest that you should actually use a combo box column, rather than a text box column. That way, the user can't possibly enter an invalid value, because they have to select either "Y" or "N" from the drop-down list.

A `DataGridView` will never create a combo box column for you though, so you need to add one yourself. You can do it in code but I would suggest that you do it in the designer. Either way, you need to set the `DataPropertyName` property of the grid column to the name of the data source column ("Active" in your case) to make it bind correctly. See my guide to adding a combo box column in the designer [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?541476).

Once you have your combo box column, you need to bind the drop-down items. In your case, you can do this:

```
Dim activeOptions = {New With {.Text = "Y", .Value = 1},
                     New With {.Text = "N", .Value = 0}}

With activeColumn
    .DisplayMember = "Text"
    .ValueMember = "Value"
    .DataSource = activeOptions
End With
```

You should do that before you set the `DataSource` of the grid.  That code creates an array of objects of an anonymous type where the `Text` values are what get displayed in the drop-down list and the `Value` values correspond to the cell values from the grid's data source.